# Highcharts - Pie slices show up invisible until interaction

Tags: highcharts

When using the Pie chart type in highcharts, something in my data is causing the slices of the pie to render as invisible until I click on each individual slice, at which point the slices will render normally. The lead lines do not have any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the 'object' style data point format, the 'color' property cannot be null. If the 'color' property is null, the slices will not render properly. This does not appear to be an issue on any other chart type. This sort of thing can show up if you are serializing objects from c# that have an unset string type color property.

The solution would be to go through each data point and use the 'delete' keyword on the 'color' property.